# How to use encrypt Cassandra password credentials in config in Quarkus?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, quarkus

**Problem Statement**

The requirement is to set encrypted password in configuration for Cassandra so that Quarkus automatically decrypts the password at runtime (like jasypt).

**Example**

```
quarkus.cassandra.auth.username=john
quarkus.cassandra.auth.password=s3cr3t  --> instead of this
quarkus.cassandra.auth.password=ENC(1k9u)  --> something like this
```

Comment: My bad, I created one critical app in Quarkus, without checking this ENC() option.  I've to rewrite it to springboot. It is sad they can't add these basic security features -- not the fancy vault ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reached out to the team who maintain the Quarkus extension for Apache Cassandra and got confirmation that unfortunately it's not possible to do that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is to use Vault as a ConfigSource. Secrets can be stored on Vault and Quarkus will read them as any other configuration source.

Please check: https://quarkus.io/guides/vault

Comment: Quarkus apps need another-system ... to run securly? (i.e without plaintext pwd)